# Color value not valid -- must be #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb, or #aarrggbb

Tags: java, android

I am giving a colour code in textColour attribute in xml file.

i.e android:textColor="#fffffffff"

I am getting this error:
Error: Color value not valid -- must be #rgb, #argb, #rrggbb, or #aarrggbb (at 'textColor' with value '#fffffffff').

Still the colour is converting to black in layout.

Although I have got that the color code is not valid, it sholud be "#ffffffff"(White), but if it is not valid then why it is converting to black?
What is happenig exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have nine `f` characters there instead of eight, which is why it's complaining. It's probably going to black because it fails validation and the default value is zero.

Answer (score 0):

To Use **transparent** Color You Need To Replace `#00000000` instead of `#FFFFFFFFF`

To Fix Error   :-)